# How to use plugins to add nodes and edges in cytoscape.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cytoscape.js

I'm trying to migrate from the old Flash CytoscapeWeb to the HTML5 version, cytoscape.js.  I'm trying to build a tool that allows interactive creation of networks - meaning we need to add nodes and edges.  There were some wonderful demos for CytoscapeWeb (eg http://cytoscapeweb.cytoscape.org/demos/compound) that demonstrated this functionality.  I can't find anything similar for Cytoscape.js.  I've looked through the documentation and I'm not finding anything.

I've tried this ([How do I use the jquery.cxtmenu.js plugin packaged with cytoscape.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19287934/how-do-i-use-the-jquery-cxtmenu-js-plugin-packaged-with-cytoscape-js)) and the context menu appears on right click, but the two commands both fail.  The Connect command simply does nothing (it's calling EdgeHandles but there's no documentation about what that's doing) and the Delete command fails with "doc.removeEntity(...) is not defined".

I get the strong sense that the functionality that I'm looking for already exists in the core or plugins, so I don't want to recreate all that stuff.  But I can't figure out how to use what's already there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Documentation and organisation of the UI plugins in the jQuery plugins system is planned for 2.1:
https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/issues?milestone=3

There is an example of those particular plugins being used on the cy.js debug page:
https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/blob/master/debug/init.js