# CytoscapeJS implementing a context menu and menu bar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu, contextmenu, cytoscape.js

I have recently started exploring **CytoscapeJS**. I used the ***'cxtmenu' plugin*** and the example at [How do I use the jquery.cxtmenu.js plugin packaged with cytoscape.js?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19287934/how-do-i-use-the-jquery-cxtmenu-js-plugin-packaged-with-cytoscape-js) to make a simple *circular* context menu. However, I do not know if it allows users to have ***sub-menus*** within each context menu item.

I actually want my web app to have a simple ***dropdown context/ popup menu*** with different options depending on the ***node/ edge*** clicked (on right click) with further sub-menus. Is this possible in cytoscapeJS ?

Also, is there a way to have a simple ***menu bar*** at the top of the graph (as in Cytoscape Web) or do I use javascript/ jquery ***outside*** the cytoscapeJS container for that ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any other libs with Cytoscape.js.  The extensions can be used to add new behaviour to Cytoscape.js, or they can be used to make integrations with other libraries more convenient for the dev.

You may be interested in this discussion re. traditional menus: https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-cxtmenu/issues/11#issuecomment-64001388

So, you could use widgets/libs from anywhere (e.g. Bootstrap, Foundation, etc).  If you want, you could make reusable extensions if that helps to make your code easier or more readable.  You're free to take whatever approach you like best.

Re. radial submenus, I have created this issue in the tracker: https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js-cxtmenu/issues/12

Comment: Any updates on the development of radial sub-menus in cytoscapeJS/ cxtmenu ?